# Oracle 12c db installation on linux mint 18.1

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, oracle12c, linux-mint

I get the following error while installing oracle 12c on linux mint 18.1 cinnamon :

```
[INS-32021] Installer has detected that the available disk space on the volume for Oracle home (/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1) is insufficient.
[INS-35212] Insufficient disk space on this volume for the selected datafiles location.
```

The output of df -h is as follows :

$ df -h

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           787M  9.4M  778M   2% /run
    /dev/sda5        41G   31G  8.0G  80% /
    tmpfs           3.9G   23M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/sda1       256M   30M  227M  12% /boot/efi
    cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
    tmpfs           787M   32K  787M   1% /run/user/1000
    overflow       1000M  778M  223M  78% /tmp
```

What should be done ?

Note :- size of /u01 is 8.6Gb.

Comment: Why doesn't your `dh` output show `/u01`? And why does your 12c home refer to 11.2.0?

Comment: @AlexPoole When i did df -h in the root directory both as a root user and oracle user. I get abovementioned output. The command dh in root returns the following output : dh dh: cannot read debian/control: No such file or directory 2. Oracle home was wrongly set, I corrected it to /u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1. But the problem remains the same.